# Where is the True Tone ambient light sensor on the 2018 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

The 2018 MacBook Pro has an ambient light sensor for its True Tone display. Where exactly is this sensor? I'm hoping for a diagram so that I know where exactly to position a webcam slider cover without blocking the sensor.

[According to MacRumors:](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2018/07/18/2018-macbook-pro-true-tone/)

> Apple says the new MacBook Pro has a multi-channel ambient light sensor, next to the FaceTime HD camera

but that isn't specific enough to tell which side or how far from the camera.

Comment: Fit the cover temporarily and see if the functionality changes...

Comment: you can start FaceTime app and see, it will light up sensor to green color and decide the webcam slider cover

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know this has been answered but I thought an image may be useful to anyone else looking for the answer.[image: Flash photo of 2018 MBP camera]

Comment: I’ve accepted this answer, because your photo is super easy to understand and much better than my text only answer. Feel free to edit in the measurements from my answer as well.

Answer (score 4):

The sensor is 1/2 inch to the right of the camera.

I pointed the display at a bright light and opened the Display system preference. I moved a small object along the top of the screen until they brightness changed.

Thanks to Solar Mike for the idea.